# How to insert Json data into a postgres table using pg-promise

Tags: json, database, postgresql, insert, pg-promise

how to add json data into POSTGRES table. like if i have a table with id and name. i should add { id : 1, name : 'abc'} into the table in both fields like id -> 1, name -> abc.

Comment: What have you tried? There's [:json](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#json-filter) filter available in the library. Are you having problems using it?

Comment: Please make you're question as beautiful.